# goto is not working in php giving syntax error, unexpected ':' on line number 10

Tags: php, mysql, goto

Below is the code i am using

```
Again:
  $rand = mt_rand(100000,999999);
  $sql = "select * from replogins where access_code = $rand";
      $res = mysql_query($sql); 
  if(mysql_num_rows($res))
goto Again;
```

please help

Comment: Please, never-ever use goto again. And stop using the old `mysql_*` functions too.

Comment: there is no reason this can't be built using a while
   `while($res) { }`

Comment: If you are using PHP 5.3, then the syntax error is caused by an unterminated construct in the preceding code you didn't show.

Comment: [Beware of the raptor!](http://xkcd.com/292/) And next time, please show which line is “line 10” (though it seems pretty straightforward here, the actual error could be triggered somewhere else). And please don't say “please help” again, it adds nothing to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could easily replace the goto with a while loop, solving your problem AND getting rid of that goto at the same time. ;)

```
do {
    $rand = mt_rand(100000,999999);
    $sql = "select * from replogins where access_code = $rand";
    $res = mysql_query($sql); 
} while(mysql_num_rows($res));
```

Answer (score 2):

Do while is realy ugly.

Why you dont select a random row?

```
Select * from replogins order by RAND()
```